# Is there any signature pad plugin available in ionic framework 5.2.1

Tags: ionic-framework, signaturepad

Is there any signature pad available in ionic framework latest version 5? I used this in ionic 3 https://devdactic.com/signature-drawpad-ionic-2/ how to update it to latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Im using this one: https://github.com/lathonez/angular2-signaturepad-demo/blob/master/src/app/signature-field/signature-field.component.ts

it work fine with ionic 4